# imagemagick install problems in centos

Tags: centos, imagemagick

i'm trying to install imagemagick on my server (centos 7.1 minimal) by this url:
[imagemagick installation steps](http://tecadmin.net/install-imagemagick-on-linux/)

get this error in step 1:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * remi: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-php55: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-php56: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-safe: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-test: remi.schlundtech.de
 * updates: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
Package gcc-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package php-devel available.
No package php-pear available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this item has been questioned on many sites, I fully explain the installation process...
this proccess tested on centos 6.5 and php56 and imagick-3.4.3(ImageMagick-7)

Change the installation process for any part that needs to be changed like as your php version or folder.

you can find lasted version of "ImageMagick" in [ImageMagick versions](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick)
; use lasted stable version.

If you have already installed "ImageMagick" several times, first remove all of them and find "ImageMagick" & "imagick" folders & files and clean all of them and continue the installation process with this process.

```
# yum remove ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

Use the following command to find a file or folder:

```
# find / -name 'ImageMagick*'
# find / -name 'imagick*
```

Find and delete all the files and folders that are displayed

**Start Installation php-pear:**

Ensure you have php-pear installed, which will be used later to install Imagick PHP module.
If you don’t have pear, you can install using Yum:

```
# yum install php-pear
```

If you see the following error:

No package php—pear available.

Error: Nothing to do

solation:

```
# cd /etc/
```

and open yum.conf

OR

```
# nano /etc/yum.conf
```

And then find and remove php* and save file

then type:

```
# yum install --enablerepo remi php-pear php-devel
```

for test success Installation:
type:

```
# yum info php-pear
```

result is something like this :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: yum.ds.stackexchange.com
stack-local-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00
Available Packages
Name        : php-pear
Arch        : noarch
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.9.4
Release     : 4.el6
Size        : 393 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
URL         : http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR
License     : BSD and PHP and LGPLv2+
Description : PEAR is a framework and distribution system for reusable PHP
            : components.  This package contains the basic PEAR components.
```

**Start Installation ImageMagick:**

```
# yum install ImageMagick
# yum install ImageMagick-devel
# pecl install Imagick
```

## Important: copy "ImageMagick" folder from "/usr/include" to "/usr/local/include" for ImageMagick find "MagickWand.h"

```
# cd /usr/include
# cp ImageMagick /usr/local/include
```

before below lines don't forget: go to "php.ini" find "disable_functions" and clean "proc_open,popen,proc_close" becuase make imagick needs these functions, after complete installation you can add this functions to your "disable_functions" on "php.ini" file.

**continue:**

```
# cd /usr/local/src 
# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.4.3.tgz
# tar xzfv imagick-3.4.3.tgz
# cd imagick-3.4.3
# phpize
# ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php56/bin/php-config
# make
# make install
```

copy Installing shared extensions:     "/usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/" this is extension dir

Copy "imagick.so" from "/usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/" to "/usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/" extension directory.

```
# cd /usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/
# cp imagick.so /usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/
```

Then, edit "php.ini", find "Dynamic Extensions" add extension=imagick.so in a empty line, don't forget there are 2 or more "php.ini" on your server, you can find all of them:

```
# find / -name 'php.ini'
```

result may be like this

```
/etc/php.ini
/usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini
```

Use this file at all stages:

```
/usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini
```

for test success Installation:

```
# php -m | grep imagick
```

result should be: `imagick`

for find all php functions and extensions use :

```
# php -m
```

now you can find "imagick" at showed list

**Don't forget:**
edit "php.ini", find "disable_functions" and add "proc_open,popen,proc_close" to disable_functions For server security!

now reboot your server

```
# reboot
```

for test imagick installation on php,  use this code at php file:

```
if(extension_loaded('imagick')) {
  $imagick = new Imagick();
  print_r($imagick->queryFormats());
}
else {
  echo 'imagick is not available.';
}
```

OR use

```
echo phpinfo();
```

Comment: Sadly it seems on a cPanel managed server the package names for core PHP packages are not standard, so do not match the remi repository ones.  Trying to `yum install --enablerepo remi php-pear php-devel` gives `file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.4.45-16.el7.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-0.2.0-7.7.1.cpanel.x86_64`. I do not know a safe way to replace ea-php-cli with php-cli from remi, and of course trying to remove ea-php-cli results in over 50 dependent php packages being removed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the repository list in your paste, you are using "remi" repository for PHP. So, just

```
yum install php-pecl-imagick
```

No need to build from sources, when a RPM package exists.

But as yum doesn't even found php-devel, check yum configuration for "exclude" line, looks like a cpanel host which replace lot of base packages by their own.

Comment: given this error :

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-php55: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-php56: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-safe: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-test: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * updates: centosmirror.netcup.net
No package php-pecl-imagick available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: As I said, check for exclude in yum configuration.

Comment: grep -r exclude /etc/yum*

Comment: this result for me

/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf:#exclude=.gov, facebook
/etc/yum.conf:exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*

Comment: i think must remove apache* httpd* from this files . ok?

Comment: Obviously you don't use CentOS, but some "panel" altered distro. Sorry, but I CANT help you more without risk to break everything. You should probably ask your distro provider.

Comment: centos  7.1 minimal
imagemagick installed successfully
thanks