# Imagick/Imagemagick install problems in CentOS 7

Tags: php, imagemagick, centos7, imagick

I never had any problems with Imagick/ImageMagick until I found out today that it no longer works. I get the notification `Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat /tmp/magick-REatKQTk`.

I tried to reinstall it according to [imagemagick install problems in centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933348/imagemagick-install-problems-in-centos) (which is all new to me).

It goes wrong on the point `# ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php56/bin/php-config`. I get the message `configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH`.

What is going wrong? I am using CentOS 7 and PHP 7.2.30.

Comment: do you have an existing php-config file on the given location?

Comment: How can I check that? 

Comment: ls /usr/local/php56/bin/php-config

Comment: if the file not exists you will get this error message:  No such file or directory

Comment: also php-config is called php.ini. Then you can use php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" to get the location of the config file and use it for the --with-php-config parameter

Comment: Thnks! There is no such file. When I try php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" I get as location Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini. But when I try ./configure --with-php-config=/etc/php.ini I get the notification -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory.

Comment: ./ means from the current directory you are in at this moment. So it means there is no configure file in the directory where you are trying to execute it from. Since you were following this description above, you should cd back to that directory and try to execute the configure file from there. So it will be cd /usr/local/src/imagick-3.4.3 and then ./configure --with-php-config=/etc/php.ini Finally you can compile it with the make command

Comment: if the configure file is the one which is not existing in this folder: /usr/local/src/imagick-3.4.3 then you should execute the phpize command again which will generate the configuration script file what you can execute after that

Comment: the thing is; php was written in C, thus the extensions are also C codes, that's why you compile them from source with make. However you don't necessary have to compile it from source. If you are not used to compile php and the packages from source, then your next issue you will face will be is that you cant find this folder: /usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/

Comment: so instead of this whole compiling imagick procedure you can use the pecl package installer: pecl install imagick
How to for this process: https://tecadmin.net/install-imagemagick-on-centos-rhel/

Comment: I did it like on the webpage you suggested. And it all works again! Thank you very much for helping me. And for your patience :)

Comment: No problem, gl! :)